# How to root my Oppo N1 (with Custom Recovery)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, oppo-coloros

I just bought a Oppo N1, so how to root it?

- [ColorOS V1.0.0](http://www.oppoforums.com/threads/n1-stable-coloros-v1-0-0i.7851/)
- [CyanogenMod CM10.2](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/hardware/oppo-n1/#images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Download:**

First download the following files:

- [oppown.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2410662&d=1385231142)
- [TWRP](http://dl.twrp.me/N1/)

**2) Installation:**

- Install `oppown.apk` and download [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu)
- Connect your N1 via USB to your computer and [get access over ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106702/how-to-install-adb-fastboot-in-cmd-with-usb-drivers)

**3) Clean-up:**

- `adb uninstall uninstall com.qualcomm.privinit`

**4) TWRP install:**

- `fastboot flash recovery twrp-X.X.X.X-N1.img`

**5) Successfully rooted!**

Comment: Direct links added by bmdixon. Thanks, I couldn't do that with my reputation.