# How to install adb/fastboot in cmd (with usb-drivers)?

Tags: adb, usb-drivers, android-sdk

I need adb for some reason, but don't know how to install it and getting the usb-drivers? I heard you have to download the full android sdk?
What is to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb

Comment: @Firelord Hmm I think this is a generally which I posted. Your link is only **method 1)** of my answer. And I'm also going to add the driver-installation.

Comment: That's precisely why I wrote possible and not complete duplicate.

Comment: I added the drivers-tutorial. Could you edit my answer and link the links with the text?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should know that there are two methods to install the Android SDK. If you only need it for a short operation via ADB or Fastboot, **1)** is the right one for you. If you do more than hoping that this command or click was the right and you are interested in Android development, you should install the adb-tools via method **2)**.

## 1) Minimal Installation:

Notice that in this method you will only install the platform-tools like adb or fastboot.

**1.1) Download:**

- Download the platform-tools for your OS from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html
- Unpack it to `<home-drive>\platform-tools`

**1.2) Mount:**

The following steps are for Windows. If you need a different OS like Linux or OSX, have a look at this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42475/91312

1. Copy the folder path.
2. Open the Windows Explorer by pressing <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>`.
3. Right-click on `This Computer` --> `Properties`.
4. `Advanced System Settings` --> `Advanced` --> `Environment Variables`.
5. Variable `PATH` --> Add a `;` (Semicolon) & your `<home-drive>\platform-tools`.
6. Save all & close.

## 2) Full Installation:

Notice that you will install the full android-sdk and not only the platform-tools.

**2.1) Download:**

- Download the full SDK for your OS from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Unpack it to `<home-drive>\sdk`

**2.2) Mount:**

The following steps are for Windows. If you need a different OS like Linux or OSX, have a look at this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42475/91312

1. Copy the platform-tools folder. For example `<home-drive>\sdk\platform-tools`.
2. Run `SDK Manager.exe` and update the platform-tools.
3. Open the windows explorer <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.
4. Right-click on `This Computer` --> `Properties`.
5. `Advanced System Settings` --> `Advanced` --> `Environment Variables`.
6. Variable `PATH` --> Add a `;` (Semicolon) & your `<home-drive>\platform-tools`.
7. Save all & close.

**Additional:**
If you now want to know why there are so many other files or try your own at building your own first app, have a look at the developer site of Google. https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

## 3) Drivers:

**3.1) Download:**

- Download the Google USB Driver from https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
- Unrar & copy the path.

**3.2) Installation (Windows):**

1. <kbd>[image]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> --> `devmgmt.msc`.
2. `Other devices` --> `android device`.
3. `Install/Update driver` --> `Manual search` --> `Select from list` --> select `Data storage device`.
4. Paste the path and select `android fastboot/adb device`.

Comment: @Firelord Yeah I had done exactly that but I couldn't because of my reputation. That's why I'm using `*link*`

Comment: Suggestion: please look into Minimal ADB and Fastboot http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790