# Android not responding, screen off and battery drop

Tags: touchscreen, lenovo, setcpu

I have a Lenovo s890 that sometimes stop responding and back after about 1 minute. I have checked the screen and seem there is no problem with the screen. On the other hand when the cell phone stops working, then the battery indicator drops significantly that is really annoying. Do you have any solution for that?

Here you can a similar video that shows the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB_w4WvDiUY

Comment: I guess you're unaware of the distinction between a forum and a Q/A site.  Consider taking a [tour](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour) and a glance at [help]. Look especially about [self-answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Hi @Firelord. Thanks so much I know the difference but finding solution in forums is so difficult at least for me but in SE  it is much much easier. It is the main reason I decided to post the solution here. Thenks.

Comment: No issues in posting a solution but as per the rules, a question field should only have a question. You can always answer your question in the answer tab. Please [edit].

Comment: See  [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/106856/96277) as an example of self-answering. I had the same reason for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I played more than 3 months with the mobile phone and this is how to solve the problem. I Guess this solusion works for other mobile phones.

If you have a lenovo s890 (or other cellphones with similar symptoms) that sometimes stops and not responding or if your battery drains suddenly or if the screen goes off and does not back, then the problem is not with battery or screen. I have seen some people that asks for help and there are loads of solution that none of them work. The solution is a problem in the kernel of OS that manages CPU of the cell phone.

First install a CPU manager app from google play for example ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.amana.android.cputuner)). Then
Decrease the maximum CPU frequency to one level down and set the governor to Ondemand (like screenshot)[image: screenshot].

I have tried other setting that none of them worked for me.