# OPO stuck in "Erasing..." while unlocking bootloader

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

I've been following [this guide](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106856/how-to-root-oneplus-one) about rooting my OnePlus One. All seemed fine - adb was good, fastboot as well - and I reached point 6.1. Typed in `fastboot oem unlock` and got this output:

```
...
OKAY [  0.023s]
finished. total time: 0.025s
```

Then my phone went into the "Erasing..." screen (where the android dangles his antennas) and has been stuck there for the past 50 minutes. I'm honestly unsure about what to do? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Boot into recovery mode and do factory reset if  data wipe didn't complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reboot the device; at this point there's no harm that can be done since the data was being wiped anyways.

Comment: Just wanted to say that after a while, that's what I did and the phone booted without any issue with data properly erased.

Comment: Few observations to this problem a) it could be caused by full disk encryption b) `fastboot oem unlock` is not supposed to automatically restart, it should wait for your `fastboot restart` c) both fastboot wipe and manual wipe may get stuck. I would recommend you to hard reset phone after waiting for 20 minutes and manually wipe from recovery. Repeat until you boot to clean system. Worked for me.

Comment: I entered `fastboot restart`, and get the message: `< waiting for any device >`. I held in the power button for 10 seconds, and a menu with 4 options appeared. I chose the first option, and my old Cyanogenmod rebooted.