# Lg stylo2 moving apps to sd card problem

Tags: external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card

I have an lg stylo2 from virgin mobile running android 6.0.1. I'm trying to free up some internal space by moving some apps to the sd card. Everything i have seen says that you go to apps, storage and click change. There's a problem. There is no change button on my phone, for any app.

[image: Screenshot]

Is this something that virgin mobile turns off or what? If i have to root the phone, which i am not opposed to, does anyone know how for this particular phone? I haven't been able to find a tutorial yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this it was a feature removed in Marshmallow update.

Quoting user **tommytm75** from the [android central forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/?utm_medium=navbar&utm_campaign=navigation&utm_source=ac):

> There is no solution yet. I have the same issue. After going back and
> forth with LG, finally someone answered my question.  This is the last
> email I got from LG.
>
> Hi Tom,
>
> Thank you for contacting LG!
>
> We regret any inconvenience you’re having.  Upon checking, I’m afraid
> that the Adoptable Storage feature  has been removed on the
> Marshmallow update of the LG G Stylo  and this means you may not be
> able to fully use the SD card as internal storage of the device. I’m
> so sorry to disappoint you in this matter.
>
> Should you have any other questions,  please feel free to contact us
> again via Email, Live Chat, or Phone by calling 1-800-793-8896.
>
> Thank you and we wish you all the best.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Edrian
> --- LG Customer Service

Source: [LG G STYLO - not enough memory on sd card?](http://forums.androidcentral.com/more-lg-phones/635049-lg-g-stylo-not-enough-memory-sd-card-2.html)

Comment: Shoot. That sucks.

Comment: It does tried to look if there was maybe a root but couldn't find one for that specific phone.

Comment: I think its a fairly new phone so the lack of a root method doesn't surprise me. Thanks for the info anyway

Answer (score 1):

**HOW TO CREATE ADOPTABLE STORAGE FOR LG G STYLO (MOVING APPS TO SD CARD)**

I have the Lg g Stylo from Boost Mobile (Model# LGLS770) running on 6.0 and spent the last 3 days on figuring out how to make my 32gb SD card my default storage now when I download stuff it goes directly to the SD Card and not to the internal storage (mostly games)

Here we go,

**NOTE:** You don't have to root your phone to do this I did this from my PC (I used  Windows 10).

1st "Download Java" -it is necessary.

You can find out where on the internet and then watch this video from Youtube if you need help installing it:

**"How to install Java JDK on Windows 10 ( with JAVA_HOME )"**.

**NOTE: pay close attention to the part of the video when you get to around 5:53 in the minutes BECAUSE YOU MUST COPY AND PASTE THE PATH EXACTLY WHERE IT IS SHOWN and not at the end of the file path which he says. It actually goes right after the 1.0\; (one point zero backslash semicolon) don't worry it will all make sense when you see the Java installation video.**

Next download the **“Android SDK Software”** from the  developer.android.com/studio   website.

Get the zipped version/file... when you unzip it you will eventually find the “platform-tools“ which holds the "adb and fastboot”  files you will need to install on your PC.

This Youtube video will help It’s what I used,

**“How to Install FASTBOOT and ADB using Android Studio on Windows PC”** 
(The one Published on Jan 16, 2016 by  Dawson, Jim)

Once all that is installed connect USB Cable from PC to your phone **(Make sure to turn your phone USB Debugging on)**

Open your computer Command Prompt (cmd.exe)

**Then enter all five (5) codes separately  type the first code then hit enter,** the second code then hit enter, third code then hit enter  ect… until all five have been entered and your done !

1. Code:
   adb shell
2. Code:
   sm set-force-adoptable true
3. Code:
   sm partition disk:179,64 private
4. Code:
   sm set-force-adoptable false
5. Code:
   sm list-volumes all

Comment: You don't need to watch any YouTube videos to install `fastboot` and `adb` on your machine: we have [step-by-step instructions](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106707/12442) on this site.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the only solution is to root phone and install App2SD ROOT PRO from Play Store. I had similar problem. Do not use Link2SD because it does not work properly with MM.

Comment: Right, but i cant do that because, as far as i know, it doesn't look like a root exists for this phone just yet.

Comment: So, try to use any App2SD app without necessity of root (there is a lot of such app in Play Store for free). It moves part of Your applications to SD (not all) but You will have more space in internal memory.